# Removing excess tabs from .txt file after user-input-error

Tags: python, pandas

We receive multiple .txt files every night from our ERP, sometimes we have product names ending in TAB after the person who inserts the product name has copy pasted it from somewhere else, long story short this breaks the process as there is python script automated that will perform very modest cleaning, and then insert the data to our MySQL database.

Now, the script that imports them to our database errors and breaks when this happens as it will push one row in the file to be 1 column longer, and i'll need to find a way to fix this from happening as when it happens it breaks our BI reporting.

I've thought of some rules on how to pin point where the user-input-error is in the file, i reckon the right way would be to write a python script to import the .txt file as a pandas dataframe, find all rows where column [amount] is blank and then fix the said row. Unfortunately to my understanding fixing can't happen in pandas, as when I import the file to pandas dataframe the problem already happened and needs to be fixed prior to importing to pandas, unless it is somehow possible to remove the blank cell from column X, and move all the other columns one step back filling the void left. This is what happens with the error rows:

[image: This is what happens with the error rows]

So i need to find a way to either move all the cells one step back(left) when column X is blank, or some other way, all help is welcome.

EDIT:
I suppose there is a way afterall to do this in pandas with shift, if anyone can assist on how to make it shift when columnX is blank, would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT2:
Here are headers in the .txt file, and 2nd row which is fine, and 3rd row which errors out:

[image: Here are headers in the .txt file, and 2nd row which is fine, and 3rd row which errors out]

```
tilausnro tasiakasnro ttkoodi lasiakasnro ltkoodi tilpvm myyja kasittelija myypri toiala tila tyonro toimpvm tryhma tuote nimi maara hinta valuutta mtili kpka s.posti kirjpvm aspvm ensvahaspvm vahvpvm tulpvm 100000-1 121007 121007 20-10-15 oer oer 8 100000-1 27-10-15 2100 ESP_734249 Wisby Hopfwis. Wei 5,6% 50EG Buk 150000 2032,26 SEK 3350 2 20-10-15 30-10-15 ? ? ? 500072-2 121110 121110 20-10-20 jra NTA 1 500072-2 21-10-20 2000 EVILN_007 Kwas Ostrabramski 0,5l back 60000 82,8 3350 600 20-10-20 23-10-20 ? ? ?
```

Comment: you can parse the data in vanilla python first, that said open your `.txt` file in notepad and post the first few rows as well as your expected output.

Comment: Hey, yeah just realized I can't even import the file to pandas as it errors out with "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 28 fields in line 43914, saw 29"

Comment: Edited original post, 2nd picture shows headers, first row(nr2) which is fine, and a row that errors out as row3. It is pretty much invisible to naked eye as we use TAB as delimiter, and there is an extra tab after 0,5l back which shifts everything to the right

Comment: can you post it as text? I can't post an image into my ide

Comment: tilausnro tasiakasnro ttkoodi lasiakasnro ltkoodi tilpvm myyja kasittelija myypri toiala tila tyonro toimpvm tryhma tuote nimi maara hinta valuutta mtili kpka s.posti kirjpvm aspvm ensvahaspvm vahvpvm tulpvm 
100000-1 121007  121007  20-10-15 oer oer   8 100000-1 27-10-15 2100 ESP_734249 Wisby Hopfwis. Wei 5,6% 50EG Buk 150000 2032,26 SEK 3350 2  20-10-15 30-10-15 ? ? ? 
500072-2 121110  121110  20-10-20 jra NTA   1 500072-2 21-10-20 2000 EVILN_007 Kwas Ostrabramski 0,5l back  60000 82,8  3350 600  20-10-20 23-10-20 ? ? ?

Comment: tbh i dont know if that makes any sense, ill upload the rows just in case and post link to the file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r4ce5G5E

Comment: what represents amount in this text file `kasittelija` ?

Comment: sorry my bad, maara = amount which is blank when I for example open the .txt file in excel for browsing, so in my mind the fix would be to somehow check for empty cells in dataframe and then shift everything 1 step left on the rows where it happens, but since I can't import it as a pandas dataframe i'm already out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this with a little help from kind people at Discord.

```
lst = open('directory//filename.txt').readlines()

fixed = []
for line in lst:
    inner = line.split('\t') #string to list
    if inner[16] == '':
        inner.pop(16)
    inner = "\t".join(inner) #list to string
    fixed.append(inner)

with open("directory//filename.txt", "w") as output:
    for item in fixed:
        output.write("%s" % item)
```